# Hey, please can someone be ever so kind and tell me the meaning of this stamp? What does it mean in English (Characters Identified 夏至)

Tags: traditional-characters, seal

[image]

Please can someone tell me what this means in English please :)

Comment: On the right-hand side, it read 夏至 (The summer solstice), and there is some flower on the left

Comment: i would further say that, it’s lotus flower, and half lotus root. both are symbols related to summer 

Comment: @水巷孑蠻 not root, but lotus leaf and lotus pod.  english is more picky about the plant names :) lotus root would only be 藕 as commonly used and not lotus in general

Comment: @zagrycha , oooops, my fault thanks for correcting me 

Comment: @水巷孑蠻 no worries, it is hard when the words are almost the same but can't be used the same way in the other language.

Answer (score 1):

It was properly answered by multiple of us in the comments.  Just typing an actual answer to make it official:

As tang ho said, it says summer solstice aka 夏至 written vertically top to bottom on the right of the image.  the left of the image is an artistic depiction of a lotus seed pod, two lotus flowers, and a lotus leaf pad-- as discussed by myself and 水巷孑蠻.

Comment: Thank you everyone 